# Smarty Exception on pdf creation Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm developing a e-commerce website based on prestashop (1.7.6.7). The invoice generation of my site worked just fine couple weeks ago, but now the exception

> SmartyException. HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Source: Missing name

Is triggered every time i try to display/create any sort of pdf document.

[image]

At first I thought that my modifications had something to do with it, but neither the controller nor any of the files involved in the error's stack trace have been modified... To make sure that my modifications haven't been the cause of this issue I disabled the override folder and the non prestashop modules.

I have also tried to delete and disable the site's cache and it didn't work. I red somewhere that this could be a prestashop's issue.

[image]

This is the dump of the object that causes the exception to trigger (the method is called several times and when it receives a false(or a undefined object I'm not sure) as a parameter the exception triggers.

Does anyone know what could be causing this exception and how could I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think we have too few info to help you. I see a tab named "Logs 2", does it contain related data? Did you change address form fields?

Comment: The logs contain the same errors that are shown in the screenshot I posted. I will update the issue with the dump of the object that causes the smarty exception.

Comment: What do you mean with address form fields? @FranCerezo

Comment: Check your override directory. You may have something in this section (cause of your modules)

Comment: Localization > Countries to change the address format for a country.